# How to use variable outside of if-statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

i'm very new to C programming. I wanted to know how do i use a variable declared in an if-statement (or just any function in general) outside of it? Example:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 0;
 
if (x > 5){
        int y = x / 5;
        printf("%d\n",y);   // outputs 20
    }

    printf("%d",y);    // outputs 0 but I wanted 20
```

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text but post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: `int z = x` -> `z = x` . `int z = x;` declares another variable `z` in the scope between the two `{}`.

Comment: BTW, the output of your code is not `20` but  `100`. You print `x`, not `y`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the question, hopefully it's clear to understand now.

Comment: You have two *different* variables, both named `y`.  This is almost always confusing, error-prone, and a bad idea — and anyway it's probably not what you want!  Inside the `if` statement, why did you say `int y = x / 5;`?  Why not just `y = x / 5;`?

Comment: If I did y = x / 5 in the if statement, i could still not use y (that outputs 20) outside of it. I just want to know, how to do that.

Comment: @SamiraValentin *i could still not use y* I don't understand.  I believe you absolutely *could*.  I suggest you try again.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry, I didn't understand the answer correctly at first but another user explained further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = 100;
int y = 0;
 
if (x > 5)
{
  int y = x / 5;   //<< here you declare a new y variable  
  printf("%d\n",y);   // outputs 20
}

printf("%d",y);    // outputs 0 but I wanted 20
```

You could as well write this, which would be equivalent to your original code:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 0;
 
if (x > 5)
{
  int foo = x / 5;
  printf("%d\n",foo);   // outputs 20
}

printf("%d",y);    // outputs 0 but I wanted 20
```

Inside the braces you declare a new `y` variable that is totally distinct from the `y` variable you've declared in the second line of your code. The only thing these two variables have in common is their name.

You want this:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 0;
 
if (x > 5)
{
  y = x / 5;            // drop the int keyword here
  printf("%d\n",y);     // and the other y variable will be used.
}

printf("%d",y);
```